# Class method picks hidden base class property over new subclass property

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a unit test for one of my classes that uses a base class from a third party library, but my first attempt is fragile as the tests depend on integration with texts managed by content managers.

First, a small repro. This will represent the third party base class I have to work with:

```
namespace ThirdPartyXyz
{
    public class SomeFancyBaseClass
    {
        public SomeFancyBaseClass()
        {
            this.myMap = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "title", "Greatness" } };
        }

        public IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> myMap { get; private set; }
    }
}
```

Then I'm unit testing code along these lines:

```
namespace MyCorp
{
    public class MyThing : ThirdPartyXyz.SomeFancyBaseClass
    {
        public string GetHeadline()
        {
            return "[" + this.myMap["title"] + "]";
        }
    }
}
```

With the following NUnit test method:

```
namespace MyCorp.UnitTestExperiments
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyThingTests
    {    
        [Test]
        public void GetHeadlineWillOutputBracketedResource()
        {
            var thing = new MyThing();
            var result = thing.GetHeadline();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("[Greatness]"));
        }
    }
}
```

This is green, but will turn red if a content manager changes the `"Greatness"` value to something else. So I'm trying to mock / stub / fake the actual dictionary from the base class, but this is not straightforward because the third party library declares `myMap`'s dictionary setter as `private`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
namespace MyCorp.UnitTestExperiments
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyThingTests
    {
        private class TestableMyThing : MyThing
        {
            public TestableMyThing(Dictionary<string, string> texts) { this.myMap = texts; }
            public new IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> myMap { get; private set; }
        }

        [Test]
        public void GetHeadlineWillOutputBracketedResource()
        {
            var fakeTexts = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "title", "test text" } };
            var thing = new TestableMyThing(fakeTexts);
            var result = thing.GetHeadline();
            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("[test text]"));
        }
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work: the test still fails. The `GetHeadline` method uses the hidden `myMap` property from `SomeFancyBaseClass` as opposed to the fake dictionary containing the `"test text"`.

My goals / questions currently are two-fold. First, by now I'm curious how I *(c/w)ould* get my current approach to work. But second, I fear my way of making `MyThing` testable is not the best one, and would like to know if there's a way to avoid this situation altogether.

Comment: Unless I'm misreading you, you appear to want to write a test against a 3rd party class that is supplied data by another party. You have no control over either. It's not testing anything useful (to you) and will be incredible fragile.So why write the test?

Comment: Ah, not sure if I explained corretly then, but I'm trying to test `GetHeadline` in `MyThing`, which is my own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options:

- Use reflection to access the `set`er of the dictionary
- Second option, make your class more easily to stub:

  ```
  public class MyThing : ThirdPartyXyz.SomeFancyBaseClass
  {
      public virtual new IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> myMap;
      {
          get { return base.myMap; }
      }

      public string GetHeadline()
      {
          // this will use your 'virtual new myMap'!
          return "[" + this.myMap["title"] + "]";
      }
  }
  ```

  Now in your unit tests you can:

  ```
  public class MyThingTestable : MyThing
  {
       public override IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> myMap { get; set; }
  }
  ```

  and now you can set the `myMap`, and your class will use it (but note that the `SomeFancyBaseClass` class won't use it! It will use its `myMap`! Not very good!)
- Third option: use Microsoft Fakes or similar product.

Comment: `myMap` is a `IReadOnlyDictionary<T, V>` so your second solution won't work.

Comment: @toadflakz Hadn't noticed... Removed the second example.